# How to get JSON Object from URL

Tags: javascript, json, web

I'm very new to web development.

When I input this link

```
https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?name=jimmy%20johns&api_key=b1f51f4ae241770f72fca5924d045733c4135412
```

into my browser, I can see the JSON object.

What do I need to do so can I use this JSON object in my javascript? I've tried using JQuery's `$.getJSON` with no luck.

EDIT

Using JSONP worked! Appending &jsonp=readJSON&?callback=? to the URL gave me back the JSON I wanted. Thank you for all the informative answers.

```
$.getJSON( "https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?name=jimmy%20johns&api_key=b1f51f4ae241770f72fca5924d045733c4135412&jsonp=readJSON&?callback=?", function() {
        console.log( "success" );
    })

    function readJSON(response){
      console.log (response);
    }
```

Comment: You would use Ajax and a sever so you can take and read that file.

Comment: You would make this an ajax request, and this would be passed into the callback function.  From there you would then assign it.

Comment: When you tried `$.getJSON()` did you get an error in your browser's console something about cross-domain requests not being allowed? (Like `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'your page here' is therefore not allowed access.`)

Comment: That api does not respond with CORS headers, but it does allow for JSONP, you will need to set the `$.getJSON` options accordingly

Comment: there's a tutorial at sitepoint here https://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/ and another on github https://gist.github.com/zuch/3720842

Comment: Using JSONP worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, is this domain (api.locu.com) the same from where you serve your files? I suppose it isn't. In this case, you have two options:

- Your backend can proxy the request from this site
- You have to use a [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) object if it's supported by the API

Answer (score 0):

This should get the concept across if you are using JQuery... but you can use just about anything.

```
var url = "https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?name=jimmy%20johns&api_key=b1f51f4ae241770f72fca5924d045733c4135412";
var result;
var settings = {
  success: function(data){
    result = data;
    //do anything else related to this data here as you need it fetched, and is not linear.
  }
}
$.ajax(url, settings);
```

Now, I noticed you used getJSON, which is pretty much the exact same.  I did not however see you use a success function, so if you did your way, have you tried:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
  result = data;
});
```

I may be mistaken, but you say: "With no luck" so i have a limited understanding as to what you tried with `$.getJSON`

Comment: The question says the OP already tried `$.getJSON()`. Switching to `$.ajax()` isn't going to solve the cross-origin issue...

Comment: Im sorry, i didnt see his error.  He just said "He want to know how"  It seems like he isnt doing anything with the result.   He posted no errors.

Comment: Yes, but he or she is new to web development and perhaps doesn't know how to check the console for errors. As indicated in comments previously, an Ajax request won't work because of the cross-domain request. But as per Patrick's comment that API does support JSON-P...

Comment: We are not here to say "this is how you open your web console" we are here to answer questions... As harsh as that sounds, OP would have a base understanding by way of any simple web / javascript tutorial online.

Comment: As experienced web developers, we know that the actual problem here is the cross-domain request.

Comment: It is an option.  I have never used locu before and as an external user jsonp would be leveraged.  I was not given enough information to know if they are an external or internal resource so i didnt want to jump to conclusions

Comment: I prefer just to jump straight to crazy conclusions. (Seriously though, in this case I had tested it with and without json-p, so I knew that it works fine with json-p. I didn't post an answer because if slezica had updated their answer as suggested by Patrick that would cover it comprehensively...)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly from inside a web browser, no. You would need to use a proxy: another server that makes this request in your behalf and then gives you the result.

### Why not?

Web browsers are pretty tight on security. One of the strategies for protecting users from malicious activity is restricting the domains your Javascript can make HTTP requests to.

An HTTP request from your domain (the *origin*) to another domain is called a **cross-origin request**. These are forbidden by default, and you won't be able to read the response body, unless the received HTTP response includes the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

### How then?

By using a proxy as an intermediary. The proxy is not a web browser, it doesn't care about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, and will read the response anyway.

There are a number of proxies you can use. An easy one is YQL (the *Yahoo Query Language*). Here's an article on the topic, using jQuery: http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax

Comment: In this case, the api allows for a JSONP response, so they can do it in the browser without needing a proxy to fetch it first.

Comment: @PatrickEvans good catch! I'll leave the answer here, because it provides an explanation and a more general solution to the problem. Would you write your own answer, with the specific JSON-P approach? I know it can be done with jQuery and little fuss, but I haven't done so in ages

Comment: I would say just add in another section to your answer about JSONP, most apis just need a `format=json` and `callback=functionName` request parameters

Comment: In this case simply adding `&callback=?` to the end of the URL is all you need for `$.getJSON()` to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no clear about your question, but I think you can use a call ajax, something like:

```
$.ajax({                       
     url: "https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?name=jimmy%20johns&api_key=b1f51f4ae241770f72fca5924d045733c4135412",
     type: 'get',
     cache: false,
     success: function (response) {
         console.log(response);
     }
});
```

Comment: This is essentially what `$.getJSON` does. If that doesn't work, neither will this, so it's not much help.